# Objective-C NSString Question

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I need to return a NSString from a function:

```
NSString myfunc ( int x )
{
    // do something with x  
    NSString* myString = [NSString string];
    myString = @"MYDATA";   
    // NSLog(myString);

    return *myString;       
}
```

So, I call this function and get *myString. Is that a pointer to the data? How can I get to the data "MYDATA"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would rewrite this function the following way:

```
NSString* myfunc( int x )
{
   NSString *myString = @"MYDATA";

   // do something with myString
   return myString;        
}
```

In Objective-C it is more common to work with pointer to objects, not objects themselves, i.e., in your example with `NSString*`, not `NSString`.

Moreover, `@"MYDATA"` is already a string, so you don't need to allocate and initialize myString before the assignment.